# Securing a string that will get executed

Tags: c#, security, delphi, windows-7, windows

I'm writing an application that runs on a windows machine with elevated privileges.

It calls an api on a web server through https and gets back a path to an executable (for example c:\windows\calc.exe)

Then the software is suppused to start that executable.

What I want to achieve is for the app to be secure against attackers who want to penetrate the machine where my app is running in case they can hack the server and make the api return an arbitrary string.

I think filtering the string for common attack vectors is a good starting point, but what am I supposed to look for in the strings?

I know there is no perfect solution in this case, but I'm looking forward to some ideas that could protect against mediocre hackers.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) disable parent path (`../`) 2) additionally(?): may be disable some file extension, let's say, you allow to have EXE, but not OCX, DLL, COM & whatever else.

Comment: Good suggestions, probably I need to filter cmd.exe, explorer.exe, and basic commands too.

Comment: DO NOT run your app elevated in this scenario! That is begging you to hand over the keys to the whole system. Run with least privileges instead, and then elevate ONLY when executing a command that actually requires elevation.

Comment: HTTPS is encrypted. Use certificates and identity verification to ensure your client app is actually communicating with your real trusted server and not someone in the middle. Then the only attack vectors are compromising the server itself (not likely) to send malicious commands before encrypting them, or compromising your client app (more likely) to ignore legitimate commands after decrypting them and instead execute malicious commands. But then your lack of elevation will prevent you from doing anything harmful unless your app is run as an admin to begin with.

Comment: The software's main purpose is to run on computers without monitors and keyboard so requiring user intervention is not an option.

Comment: I've also specifically asked about an unlikely scenario where my server gets hacked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't accept arbitrary command strings. Instead, send from a fixed list of known values — a *whitelist*. On the receiving end, translate the value into the corresponding command string. For example, if you have 10 commands to run, send a number between 1 and 10.

Comment: The whole point is for me to be able to execute an arbitrary software, that I cannot predict, and put in a whitelist.

Comment: If you really accept *arbitrary* commands, then you cannot tell the difference between a command from a normal server and one from a compromised server. A compromised server can tell clients to run whatever they want because that's exactly what you designed a *normal* server to do. You wrote your own backdoor.

Comment: @sevron Your expectations are unrealistic. You'd like to give malicious people elevated access to your machine? That's just silly.

Comment: I want to be able to run software that is needed for work on an unattended machine. Protecting against malicious strings is just an additional line of security in case everything else fails.

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing Ansible or Symantec Management Agent.